# No output when stored procedure is executed

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, procedure

No output when stored procedure is executed.  The select statement works when I create a new query , but does not return any values when calling the store procedure within my Web app.

Comment: This looks like SQL Server code, not Oracle.  Why is it tagged Oracle?  Are you expecting one of the two parameters to be interpreted as the name of a column rather than a bind variable?  If so, you'd need to use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a dynamic sql.
try this.

```
Declare @strSQL nvarchar(2000)
set @strSQL = 'SELECT * FROM investor WHERE ' + @search_by + ' = ''' + @col + ''''
execute sp_executesql @strSQL
```